# Where should a property be injected?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection

Reading the book of Mark Seemann - Dependency Injection in .NET made me think more about implementing his concepts, but also observing some missing parts.
  He specifies pretty everywhere aspects about constructor injection and where this should take place, and how , but he speaks so little about the injection time of a property.

> If only the Composition Root should be my only entrance point which knows all my dependencies, then where should a property be set to the new dependency (because a local default is mandatory)?

If I do that right away in the CR then what's the point of a local default?

> So, in order to use the Property Injection pattern the right way, am i constrained to assign only implementations from the same assembly which can be anywhere outside the Composition Root?

This of course can lead to fuzzy waters making me wonder if an interface property can be overall still helpful?

> If the main purpose of an abstract property is to allow Strategies (design pattern) then probably I am better of with an Abstract Factory injected eventually also in my constructor?

Answer to:
@Siram Sakthivel, I'll up-vote it because of the beautiful schema that I am sure is very constructive for others without Mark's book. I am not pleased because It is also specified inside the book that all dependencies (except Method injection and Ambient context) have to be known and assigned inside the CR. So immediately at the beginning ! Why initialize a property inside the CR at the beginning when I already have a local default? If I choose not to do it (because of the local default) then i am constrained to do it along the way with only concrete types that are in the same assembly, because otherwise I''ll be heading in the wrong way (Bastard injection) as you beautifully mentioned.

Strategy pattern source Gang of Four .Net optimized (I bought that damn thing :)):

```
 static void Main()
    {
        // Two contexts following different strategies
        var studentRecords = new SortedList()
          {
            new Student{ Name = "Samual", Ssn = "154-33-2009" },
            new Student{ Name = "Jimmy", Ssn = "487-43-1665" },
            new Student{ Name = "Sandra", Ssn = "655-00-2944" },
            new Student{ Name = "Vivek", Ssn = "133-98-8399" },
            new Student{ Name = "Anna", Ssn = "760-94-9844" },
          };

        studentRecords.SortStrategy = new QuickSort();
        studentRecords.SortStudents();

        studentRecords.SortStrategy = new ShellSort();
        studentRecords.SortStudents();

        studentRecords.SortStrategy = new MergeSort();
        studentRecords.SortStudents();

        // Wait for user
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The 'Strategy' interface
/// </summary>
interface ISortStrategy
{
    void Sort(List<Student> list);
}

 /// <summary>
/// A 'ConcreteStrategy' class
/// </summary>
class ShellSort : ISortStrategy
{
    public void Sort(List<Student> list)
    {
        // ShellSort();  not-implemented
        Console.WriteLine("ShellSorted list ");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// A 'ConcreteStrategy' class
/// </summary>
class MergeSort : ISortStrategy
{
    public void Sort(List<Student> list)
    {
        // MergeSort(); not-implemented
        Console.WriteLine("MergeSorted list ");
    }
}
```

Comment: The book contains a list of items that you should inject and those that you probably shouldn't. Look for the bit about volatile and non-volatile dependencies. Also, the book contains a flowchart that highlights when to use which type of injection. Easy.

Answer (score 4):

Property injection is no special in composing objects. You'll have to do it as you do with constructor injection. Only difference is that with constructor injection, you'll not be able to create an instance without passing the dependency. It is mandatory.

On the other hand, property injection is optional. You may inject a property; you mayn't. But the class is the question will not be affected even if you don't inject the property; because a Local Default is already available(requirement of property injection).

> If I do that right away in the CR then what's the point of a local
>   default?

Local default helps the class to work even if the client doesn't inject the property. It is optional, you may inject it, not necessarily you inject always.

> So, in order to use the Property Injection pattern the right way, am i
>   constrained to assign only implementations from the same assembly
>   which can be anywhere outside the Composition Root?

If the class in the question provides a local default, it should be defined in the same assembly, if it refers to some other assembly then it is called as Bastard Injection anti-pattern which you want to avoid.

You can inject any dependency from any assembly when you inject it from Composition Root.

> This of course can lead to fuzzy waters making me wonder if an
>   interface property can be overall still helpful?

I'm not sure what you mean by this; A property exposed as interface type is helpful if you can implement the interface in another assembly and inject it in the composition root. Not necessarily in another assembly, you can have multiple implementations in same assembly itself but it is not common.

Remember you must strive hard to use constructor injection always. Only use other patterns if constructor injection can't satisfy your needs.

When choosing between which type of injection pattern to use, Mark Seemann's flowchart in choosing the injection pattern will he helpful. Refer Dependency Injection in .NET - Mark Seemann Page 131.

[image]

Comment: Please do read my answer in the question (here is not enough space)

Comment: I think you're missing the point. A good example is something like logging can be implemented as local default with property `ConsoleLogger` which writes to the console, but if you want it to be written in database or something else, you'd create `DatabaseLogger` and inject it in composition root. With this 99% you will be using only `ConsoleLogger` which is the local default, but it gives you the freedom of logging to anywhere providing `ILogger` as property which you can inject. I can't think of better example, usually Logger will not be used as property injection, it is a contrived example.

Comment: If at a special moment i want to stop using the ConsoleLogger and go for the DatabaseLogger , what do I do, update the composition root while my application is running ?  Please bear in mind that the dependency should be assigned only once (that is what he says)! With more you are helping me with examples the more I realize that is a flow in the entire concept. I stick with - if is a property injection then use it as a strategy with only the types from it's own assembly. Please do have a look at the strategy pattern in my answer.

Comment: Yes if you want to swap the implementation, you'll have to modify the CR and recompile your application. If you don't prefer to recompile it, you can store the class names in app.config and you can instantiate it dynamically with `Activator.CreateInstance`. This way you don't have to recompile your application. And you can inject the property as many times as you want. Nothing stops you from doing it. Mark, in his book prevented setting the property more than once because it suited his example not because the pattern itself mandates it.